# Hibernate doesn't start

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I have the following hibernate config on spring and the server starts after a long time but doesn't connect to DB (no schema on DB). So It was supose to give a error message or create the schema with `<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>`.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method = "close"> 
    <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://dburl:3306"/>
    <property name="user" value="user"/>
    <property name="password" value="pass!"/>
</bean>


<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>waf/resources/User.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>waf/resources/Post.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>waf/resources/Position.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>waf/resources/Comment.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
            <!-- C3P0 CONNECTION POOL -->
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</prop>              
            <prop key="c3p0.acquire_increment">1</prop>             
            <prop key="c3p0.idle_test_period">100</prop>
            <prop key="c3p0.max_size">20</prop>
            <prop key="c3p0.max_statements">50</prop>
            <prop key="c3p0.min_size">1</prop>
            <prop key="c3p0.timeout">10</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource"/>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager"> 
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref bean="sessionFactory"/>
    </property> 
</bean>
```

Can you guys help me out?

Comment: Can you show us your entity classes?

Comment: Does your user have the neccesary privilages granted?

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate does not create schemas with `hbm2ddl.auto`. It just creates | creates-drop | etc tables.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean... Anyway... The server starts up, but doesn't connect to DB.

Answer (score 0):

Going through the HBM files, you have given as below..

**Validate** instead of **Create**

I hope this will not create the DDL. can you please check that? Or is it a typo in question?

Comment: Yes, this will not create, this will give an error. I tried both, create and validate. In both cases, server starts after some time with no errors.

Comment: For those with same problem, C3P0ConnectionProvider in hibernate 4 is in a diferent place. Not org.hibernate.connection but org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal. Still didn't worked. I removed the code for <!-- C3P0 CONNECTION POOL --> and works.

Comment: I am having the same problems see my thread here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14640193/hibernate-is-not-even-trying-to-connect I have already done this. Any other things I should try?

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what others have proposed if you are using connection pool (which you are as c3po is mentioned) then while the session Factory is created it will try to use the connection pool backed datasource which in turn will  connect to database to pre-create and pool connection. When you say that it does  not connect to database - how do you know that ? Is there error in logs? I have seen that if Hibernate session factory is not able to configure itself it throws an error in the logs.